# Custom layout with labelled children

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**UPDATE:** It seems that TableView offers a lot of the functionality I was looking for.

**Original Question:**
I have a custom layout (StackLayout as the base) which contains a list of children.  For each child I want to add a label - the xaml might look something like this:

```
<ContentList>
  <Entry ContentList.Header="Entry 01" Placeholder="Text here"/>
  <Entry ContentList.Header="Entry 02" Placeholder="Text here"/>
</ContentList>
```

Which would result in:

```
<ContentList>
  <Label Text="Entry 01"/>
  <Entry Placeholder="Text here"/>
  <Label Text="Entry 02"/>
  <Entry Placeholder="Text here"/>
</ContentList>
```

So far I've created the layout based off StackLayout and can add children as normal, but I'm having trouble working out how to apply the additional labels. I've tried overriding the `OnChildAdded` method but no luck and not sure what to try next.

```
public partial class ContentList : StackLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Header", typeof(string), typeof(ContentList));

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ContentList ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private Label _label;
    protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
    {
        if (child != _label)
        {
            _label = new Label {Text = "LABEL"};
            Children.Add(_label);   // this causes an exception
        }

        base.OnChildAdded(child);
    }
}
```

Perhaps the best option would be to use `[ContentProperty]` to specify a new view collection and take full control of child creation, but that would seem to negate the usefulness of basing the view off a stack.

Comment: What is your question? What did you try, which problems did you have?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the additional labels dynamically? In Run time?

Comment: @PaulKaram Yes, that might be a better way to put it.

Comment: Then it would be good and better to post the code you have tried, and to clarify when do you want to add those additional labels during run time.

Comment: Try to use `child.Add(_label);` instead of `Children.Add(_label);` And it would be useful to add the exception you're getting in case this doesn't solve it.

Comment: `Add` doesn't appear to be a valid method on Element types.

Comment: Then what you can do is, `child.Children.add(_label)`, sorry for the one before. If you have access to Children from child. And one more note, `if (child != _label)` might always be `true`. I think what you want to test that `if (typeof(child) != Label)`

Comment: Haha, no I tried that one too! I'll breakpoint it though, maybe that'll help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149990/discussion-between-paul-karam-and-ben-catterall).